# Hive logs are showing on terminal? How to disable them? Hive logs are not storing in /tmp/user/hive.log file

Tags: hadoop, logging, hive, log4j, log4j2

I am using hive 3.1.2 and hadoop 3.3.6. Whenever i Start hive shell there is just too much logs like this

```
2023-07-15 13:24:52,407 INFO  [main] conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:findConfigFile(187)) - Found configuration file file:/home/god/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
Hive Session ID = c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0
2023-07-15 13:24:55,449 INFO  [main] SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1227)) - Hive Session ID = c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/god/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2023-07-15 13:24:55,528 INFO  [main] SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1227)) - 
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/god/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2023-07-15 13:24:57,056 INFO  [main] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(790)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/god/c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0
2023-07-15 13:24:57,088 INFO  [main] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(790)) - Created local directory: /tmp/god/c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0
2023-07-15 13:24:57,094 INFO  [main] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(790)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/god/c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0/_tmp_space.db
2023-07-15 13:24:57,118 INFO  [main] conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:getLogIdVar(5040)) - Using the default value passed in for log id: c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0
2023-07-15 13:24:57,118 INFO  [main] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:updateThreadName(441)) - Updating thread name to c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main
2023-07-15 13:24:58,415 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:newRawStoreForConf(717)) - 0: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2023-07-15 13:24:58,455 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:correctAutoStartMechanism(638)) - datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode is set to unsupported value null . Setting it to value: ignored
2023-07-15 13:24:58,467 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:initializeHelper(481)) - ObjectStore, initialize called
2023-07-15 13:24:58,469 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] conf.MetastoreConf (MetastoreConf.java:findConfigFile(1240)) - Found configuration file file:/home/god/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
2023-07-15 13:24:58,472 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] conf.MetastoreConf (MetastoreConf.java:findConfigFile(1233)) - Unable to find config file hivemetastore-site.xml
2023-07-15 13:24:58,472 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] conf.MetastoreConf (MetastoreConf.java:findConfigFile(1240)) - Found configuration file null
2023-07-15 13:24:58,475 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] conf.MetastoreConf (MetastoreConf.java:findConfigFile(1233)) - Unable to find config file metastore-site.xml
2023-07-15 13:24:58,475 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] conf.MetastoreConf (MetastoreConf.java:findConfigFile(1240)) - Found configuration file null
2023-07-15 13:24:58,773 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.Persistence (Log4JLogger.java:info(77)) - Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2023-07-15 13:24:59,130 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] hikari.HikariDataSource (HikariDataSource.java:<init>(71)) - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-15 13:24:59,895 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] hikari.HikariDataSource (HikariDataSource.java:<init>(73)) - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-15 13:24:59,962 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] hikari.HikariDataSource (HikariDataSource.java:<init>(71)) - HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2023-07-15 13:25:00,045 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] hikari.HikariDataSource (HikariDataSource.java:<init>(73)) - HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2023-07-15 13:25:00,238 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getPMF(670)) - Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2023-07-15 13:25:00,558 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(186)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
2023-07-15 13:25:00,560 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(396)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2023-07-15 13:25:00,916 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:00,938 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:00,940 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:00,940 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:00,942 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:00,943 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:03,562 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:03,564 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:03,565 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:03,566 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:03,567 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:03,568 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] DataNucleus.MetaData (Log4JLogger.java:warn(96)) - Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2023-07-15 13:25:06,866 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultCatalog(730)) - Setting location of default catalog, as it hasn't been done after upgrade
2023-07-15 13:25:06,913 WARN  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getDatabase(999)) - Failed to get database hive.default, returning NoSuchObjectException
2023-07-15 13:25:07,027 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(812)) - Added admin role in metastore
2023-07-15 13:25:07,037 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(821)) - Added public role in metastore
2023-07-15 13:25:07,091 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:addAdminUsers_core(861)) - No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
2023-07-15 13:25:07,277 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient (RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:<init>(97)) - RetryingMetaStoreClient proxy=class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient ugi=god (auth:SIMPLE) retries=1 delay=1 lifetime=0
2023-07-15 13:25:07,316 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(895)) - 0: get_all_functions
2023-07-15 13:25:07,318 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(347)) - ugi=god ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_functions   
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
2023-07-15 13:25:07,354 INFO  [c69e4b21-2df2-4434-965c-5c7a5255f6a0 main] CliDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1227)) - Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Hive Session ID = 787c32b2-34f2-4af4-988b-e359b0a194a0
2023-07-15 13:25:07,355 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1227)) - Hive Session ID = 787c32b2-34f2-4af4-988b-e359b0a194a0
2023-07-15 13:25:07,391 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(790)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/god/787c32b2-34f2-4af4-988b-e359b0a194a0
2023-07-15 13:25:07,396 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(790)) - Created local directory: /tmp/god/787c32b2-34f2-4af4-988b-e359b0a194a0
2023-07-15 13:25:07,403 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(790)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/god/787c32b2-34f2-4af4-988b-e359b0a194a0/_tmp_space.db
2023-07-15 13:25:07,405 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(895)) - 1: get_databases: @hive#
2023-07-15 13:25:07,410 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(347)) - ugi=god   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases: @hive#
2023-07-15 13:25:07,416 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:newRawStoreForConf(717)) - 1: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2023-07-15 13:25:07,417 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:initializeHelper(481)) - ObjectStore, initialize called
2023-07-15 13:25:07,441 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(186)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
2023-07-15 13:25:07,442 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(396)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2023-07-15 13:25:07,457 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(895)) - 1: get_tables_by_type: db=@hive#default pat=.*,type=MATERIALIZED_VIEW
2023-07-15 13:25:07,458 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(347)) - ugi=god   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_tables_by_type: db=@hive#default pat=.*,type=MATERIALIZED_VIEW  
2023-07-15 13:25:07,472 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(895)) - 1: get_multi_table : db=default tbls=
2023-07-15 13:25:07,472 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(347)) - ugi=god   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_multi_table : db=default tbls=  
2023-07-15 13:25:07,481 INFO  [pool-9-thread-1] metadata.HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry (HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.java:run(171)) - Materialized views registry has been initialized
```

here's what i tried so far:

1. starting hive like this: `hive --hiveconfig hive.root.logger=(ERROR or FATAL or OFF)(console or DRFA)` all of the combinations, but it didn't work.
2. changing every property in `hive-log4j.properties` to ERROR or FATAL or OFF but id didn't work either
3. changing property `hive.async.log.enabled` to false in hive-site.xml.
4. changing hadoop3.3.6 to 3.3.0 and 3.3.5 and 3.2.4 but id didn't work either.
5. tried changing `hive.log.dir` in hive-log4j2.properties but that didn't work either

I noticed that all logs are only showing in terminal but they are not getting written in hive.log file in /tmp/user/hive.log

So please tell me where is the actual problem cause i have searched the internet and i couldn't find anything other than what i have already tried.

In Hive official site hadoop3.x.y is supported by hive 3.1.2 but still i tried version 3.1.3 but that didn't work either.

I am using linux Mint 21

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Ubuntu but not in Linux mint.

Comment: Both are Debian based, and Java/log4j2 doesn't care since the JVM should be the exact same... Sounds like you may have had other Java/Hive installation configurations causing conflict that a brand new OS wouldn't have

Answer (score 0):

You can change this file `hive-log4j2.properties` under `/home/.../apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/`

With this

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
log4j.appender.file.fileName=/tmp/user/hive.log
```

Check the ownership and permissions of the log file and directory. Ensure that the Hive user has the required permissions to write to the log file.

If the log file still doesn't receive the logs, you can try specifying a different log file location and ensure that the new location is writable by the Hive user.